# Program Arduino in VSCode with several archives unified

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino

i've programming with Arduino IDE for too much time, and since 6 months i've use VSCode. But since 1 month i looked for some way to program in VS as in Arduino IDE (Photo)

Programe Structure :

[image]

Here, we see 3 archives in the same proyect that works together... But when i open it in VSCode, the code works that if the lines that calls the subrutines that are included in a different archive (one of the archive that works together) doesnt exist

Subrutine call :

[image]

this appears an error because VSCode thinks that isnt declared in the program, because is done, in fact arduino IDE doesnt show that problem.

Is like VS doesn't recognize all that archives as a unique proyect composed by several "miniarchives"

How i can do for solve it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your usage of the term *"archive"* in this context. Do you mean a header file? A library?

Comment: ok... I'll try to explain it...when you create .ino archive you must store it in a folder. Then, if you create another .ino archive, in the same folder, it starts to work together... as contiuation of the code, but in other site... For example, in one .ino archive you have the main code with the subrutines calls, and in the other, you have your subrutines... Better?, i dont know how explain it

Comment: OKAY, I see it now. Can we see the rest of your code? It's hard to tell otherwise. From an initial guess, it might be because VSCode wants the other `.ino` files to be imported as well, or added to the `IncludePath.`

Comment: i tryed to include it in IncludePath. but doesn't matter... is like they aren't connect. I put the route of the folder where are storaged the 3 archives that compose the proyect but nothing... Could be that i need a plugin?